# httpd and curl: Configure https connection prom a p12 file form client validation

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, httpd

I'm deploying an httpd. I need to configure ssl in order to validate client according to its client certificate.

In order to do that I've a `p12` file containing private key, client certificate, and chain ca certificates:

**CA chain certs**:

```
➜ ~ openssl pkcs12 -in fitxers.p12 -cacerts -nokeys
Bag Attributes
    ...
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
$$$$$$$...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    ...
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
$$$$$$$...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Client cert**:

```
➜ ~ openssl pkcs12 -in fitxers.p12 -clcerts -nokeys
Bag Attributes
    ...
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
$$$$$$$...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Client private key**:

```
➜ ~ openssl pkcs12 -in fitxers.p12 -nocerts
Bag Attributes
    ...
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
$$$$$$$...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In order to split this `p12` file into separated cert and key files:

```
➜ ~ openssl pkcs12 -in container.p12 -nocerts -out client.key.pem
➜ ~ openssl pkcs12 -in fitxers.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out client.crt
➜ ~ openssl pkcs12 -in fitxers.p12 -cacerts -nokeys -out cacerts.crt
```

So, from now on, I've configured my httpd as:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/cacerts.crt
...
```

I'm trying to make te connection using curl:

```
curl --cert client.crt --key client.key.pem https://localhost:8080/token -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
Enter PEM pass phrase:
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

Into httpd server logs I'm getting:

```
[Tue Sep 17 11:17:28.144219 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 8:tid 139871525332736] [client 10.0.2.4:52926] AH01964: Connection to child 68 established (server 10.0.2.47:443)
[Tue Sep 17 11:17:28.148318 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 8:tid 139871525332736] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2375): [client 10.0.2.4:52926] AH02645: Server name not provided via TLS extension (using default/first virtual host)
[Tue Sep 17 11:17:28.155178 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 8:tid 139871525332736] [client 10.0.2.4:52926] AH02008: SSL library error 1 in handshake (server 10.0.2.47:443)
[Tue Sep 17 11:17:28.155569 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 8:tid 139871525332736] SSL Library Error: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown (SSL alert number 46)
[Tue Sep 17 11:17:28.155609 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 8:tid 139871525332736] [client 10.0.2.4:52926] AH01998: Connection closed to child 68 with abortive shutdown (server 10.0.2.47:443)
[Tue Sep 17 11:19:01.114529 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 8:tid 139871448463104] [client 10.255.0.2:48060] AH01964: Connection to child 69 established (server 10.0.2.47:443)
[Tue Sep 17 11:19:01.114667 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 8:tid 139871448463104] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2354): [client 10.255.0.2:48060] AH02044: No matching SSL virtual host for servername localhost found (using default/first virtual host)
[Tue Sep 17 11:19:01.114674 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 8:tid 139871448463104] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2354): [client 10.255.0.2:48060] AH02044: No matching SSL virtual host for servername localhost found (using default/first virtual host)
[Tue Sep 17 11:19:01.114679 2019] [core:debug] [pid 8:tid 139871448463104] protocol.c(2314): [client 10.255.0.2:48060] AH03155: select protocol from , choices=h2,http/1.1 for server 10.0.2.47
[Tue Sep 17 11:19:01.117705 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 8:tid 139871448463104] [client 10.255.0.2:48060] AH02008: SSL library error 1 in handshake (server 10.0.2.47:443)
[Tue Sep 17 11:19:01.117827 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 8:tid 139871448463104] SSL Library Error: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca (SSL alert number 48)
[Tue Sep 17 11:19:01.117858 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 8:tid 139871448463104] [client 10.255.0.2:48060] AH01998: Connection closed to child 69 with abortive shutdown (server 10.0.2.47:443)
```

I've also tried using `cacerts.pem` with `curl --cacert ./cacerts.pem --cert client.crt --key client.key.pem https://localhost:8080/token -v`

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `--cacert` with your file?

Comment: I've tried with `curl --cacert ./cacerts.pem --cert client.crt --key client.key.pem https://localhost:8080/token -v`, with the same behavior...

Comment: Does your cacerts.pem contains the needed CA certificate? You can check out what certificate the server showing by: openssl s_client -showcerts -connect localhost:8080

Comment: I think the problem raises in the fact that I don't have the rootCA... and I'm not able to generate key/certificate into httpd to set `SSLCerticateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile`. I mean, I'm using ones that they aren't the same rootCA...

Comment: Check both the cacert.pem file and the client.crt file.  The former should have only the self-signed root CA which signed the server's certificate chain.  The latter should have the client certificate and any subordinate CA certificates which signed it.

Comment: The question should be: Is there any way to generate a server key/certificate without rootCA keys/certifacte, in order to set ssl context into https?

Comment: The only alternative is a self-signed certificate on the https server.

Comment: I only have the `p.12` file since my customer has sent them to me. I'd like to test connectivity before deploying new certificate on customer environment. In order to do that, I thought to set my local httpd with new certificates, but I've just realized it's not possible since I'm not able to generate new server certificates under CA customer... are you agree?

Comment: Absolutely correct - if you could do that then all the PKIs in the world would be broken.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -out file.key.pem -nocerts -nodes
$ openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -out file.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys

$ curl -k --cert ./file.crt.pem --cert-type PEM --key ./file.key.pem --key-type PEM --pass password  "https://<server-ip>:443/actuator/health"
```